# UITableView custom drag&drop (Trello style)

Tags: ios, uitableview, drag-and-drop

I'm working on an implementation of a drag&drop of cells in an UITableView different than the standard, what means without the three lines icon. The user can drag by holding the tap anywhere on the cell and move this cell to any other position. The app Trello does something like that. Is there any library already done? Or anyone has some hint on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [this](https://github.com/FlorianMielke/FMMoveTableView) library. they have implemented without three lines.

Comment: This works only on single UITableView. How can I achieve drag and drop between UITableViews same like Trello?